# Playing music in background ios app

Tags: ios

In my code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"www/media/BlueZedEx" ofType:@"mp3"]];

AVAudioPlayer *click = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];

NSLog(@"goldenace launchOptions = %@", musicFile);
click.delegate = self;
click.numberOfLoops = -1;
[click play];

}
```

But nothing music play when I run my app in simulator.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

use this for Playing Background Audio:

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
 NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &setCategoryError];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10432512/966351)

Comment: Please give me more clear about your answer, i'm doing with my first ios app. How I can using above code and how I can play my music when I use this code.

Comment: Use above code on '- (void) viewDidLoad'. It will handle playing background audio while device is locked.

Comment: Oh, but I want the music play through from 1 screen, and when I go to 2 screen this music still play, not reload again. How can I do like that. Thanks

Comment: @NguyenAnhTuan Might be a bad advice from my side here, but an idea could be to play it from AppDelegate? I somehow feel like stuff really shouldn't be run from there, but I guess it could work if you create a method in your AppDelegate, and access it from your view where you want it to start playing.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
www/media/BlueZedEx
```

is not a filename.
It needs to be a filename of a audio file inside your project (drag and drop)