# control audio play in background

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, background, subview

I have a tablewview and by click a table row a subview appear as player and play audio in my app . I added play in background mode and controls it while in background , it works .

The problem I have is , when I move to another view (exactly when the subview being disappear) I can't control or stop the audio.

how can I let the controls keep detect the audio playing while I'm in any other views of my app? also how can I let the subview appear when I back to my view again to allow stop or show the progress status?

I hope anybody can help

Answer (score 0):

You will have to keep a Strong reference to your view, or, at least, to your object currently playing a sound.

I'll suggest using a protocol between viewControllers to let the parent view controller catch the reference before dismissing the view containing the player.

You'll find much more explanation at [Ray Wenderlich website's Audio playing tutorial.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/259/audio-tutorial-for-ios-playing-audio-programatically)

Comment: how can I do that ? could you give more explanation? or keywords to search about in apple documentation

Comment: I edited my answer by adding a reference to a complete tutorial about audio playing on iOS

Answer (score 0):

Please see the above link to find this solution and must read "Comment"... :)

[Playing music in background ios app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494064/playing-music-in-background-ios-app)

another link may help you...[iOS SDK : playing music on the background and switching views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467533/ios-sdk-playing-music-on-the-background-and-switching-views)

Comment: it's about define my player in appdelegate , but I'm using online audio with its info that plays as stream using AudioStreamer .. I can't use it in appDelegate :(