# Play sound even home button is press

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am developing an ios application on iPad and I'm playing an audio on it but when I press the home button or the lock button the sound's stopped and when I go to app again it resume. What I want is to resume playing the audio even I press the Home button or the lock button. What should i do? Is there a way to do it.

Comment: you can refer http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_background-audio/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429204/how-to-handle-background-audio-playing-while-ios-device-is-locked-or-on-another

Comment: I guess you are new so first always try to use Google you'll get the answer and if not then ask here !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set audio for UIBackgroundModes key in your app’s Info.plist file, you can get detail info about UIBackgroundModes from below link,
[UIBackgroundModes key in Info.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22)

Comment: Got it. I added Required Background Modes on info.plist