# iOS 8 - What limitations are placed on apps running in background that use alarm/notifications?

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing a Swift app for a course I'm taking. The app would essentially be an alarm app but I have read some things about iOS 8 which concern me. It seems that any app that runs in the background (eg when the phone is locked before bedtime) won't work the same way Apple's internal alarm app works. It could only use Local Notifications which create a prompt that requests action from the user. I noticed that there is an iOS app called Rise which is designed to opt-out of multitasking (which means it is either in the foreground or off completely) but it must be in the foreground when the phone is locked for its alarm to work. Is there any way to work around this? I don't see a way for a background app to work as an alarm except with Local Notifications, which isn't ideal. It seems the only way to get this to work would be to use the same paradigm as Rise, but if Apple ever decides to disallow apps to be non-multitasking it would break the alarm feature.

If anyone has dealt with this problem please let me know if there is anything I can do, or if there are any creative work-arounds. Thanks!

Comment: You can choose a sound also for your notification

Comment: Maybe start playing ipod music in the background? I haven't dealt with this but I figured it's worth a shot... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10432512/966351