# AVPlayer stop playing music when turn off the screen

Tags: ios, avplayer

My project related music and I have a problem stop playing music when turn off the screen. Although I registered background modes (Audio) but sometime when I turn off screen AVPlayer stopped playing music and played again when turn on the screen.

I spent a lot of time, but I can know why it happened.

Comment: You can find the right answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429204/how-to-handle-background-audio-playing-while-ios-device-is-locked-or-on-another

Comment: Following this answer I used the way for my app but the problem still appears

Comment: Is the audio streamed from internet or is in a local file?

Comment: Stream from the internet

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough to only add the `audio` background mode. You must also set a playback audio session category, as [described in Apple QA1668](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1668/_index.html):

> A: You must declare your app plays audible content while in the background, and assign an appropriate category to your audio session.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
if (!success) { /* handle the error condition */ }

NSError *activationError = nil;
success = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
if (!success) { /* handle the error condition */ }
```

Comment: I have this and it still dies when the screen gets turned off.

Comment: This answer is incomplete: you must also be playing audio (or, oddly enough, recording).

Comment: If this answer is incomplete, do you have a solution to complete it? Do you still experience the same issue?

Comment: Maybe the answer is ok for this question, as the question implies that music was playing... However are you playing video? The linked QA document  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1668/_index.html says that an `AVPlayer` playing video will be paused on transitioning to the background. Are you playing video? The QA suggests two work arounds for this.

Comment: I'm playing audio already using AVPlayer and registeredBackgroundNotifications, then it transitions to background and continues playing. Then when the screen turns off the song stops playing.

Comment: Can you start a new question & show your `AVPlayer` and `AVAudioSession` configuration code & what you're doing with the background notifications?

Comment: Will do. I'm going to verify I'm not getting an activation error first. Thanks.