# Cordova plugin enabling a music player to play while phone locked

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, audio-player

I am developing a Ionic app that includes a music player. It works well but when I lock my screen in an iOS device the music stops. I've searched some solution but haven't found one, is there a quick solution or a plugin enabling this or should I need to find someone to code a Cordova plugin to enable this?

Comment: may be helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429204/how-to-handle-background-audio-playing-while-ios-device-is-locked-or-on-another

Comment: Thank you very much, but are you sure that I can use it in a Ionic app? The code seems to be written in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used this plugin:
https://github.com/AubreyHewes/cordova-background-audio

```
ionic plugin add nl.kingsquare.cordova.background-audio --save
# OR
ionic plugin add https://github.com/AubreyHewes/cordova-background-audio.git --save # latest
```

Comment: Do you have the same thing working on both Android and iOS platform? This one is only for iOS...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you'll have to use two plugins. For Android we use https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin. And this one is Android and Windows only!
You can make a distinction in your config.xlm by placing them in the right `<platform name="...">` tags and in your project (Android needs some coding) by putting it in a `if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {...}` statement.

Maybe one day, I will make a plugin for both, but that didn't fit in my projects budget. So, right now functionality is a bit different.