# iOS switch between playing sounds in background and not playing

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avaudioplayer, audio-player

I am working on music app and it has feature of switching between playing/not playing music when app minimized.
How can I do it?

I use that code to enable playing in backgound, but how can I disable it?

```
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: you can check this topic, it seems to me it is related to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429204/how-to-handle-background-audio-playing-while-ios-device-is-locked-or-on-another