# Playing music at back ground: AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification not fired

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

My app is playing in **background well.**  **Pause** and **play** also works well even my app is background using the methods registered for `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification`.

The problem arrives steps for the scenario:

1. Launch my app -> goes background music from my app playing well
2. launch apple's music app and play. **AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification fired**.
3. When i pause the music app or kill the music app. **AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification doesn't get fired**

Code:
I am doing this in **appdelegate**.  **didfinishlaunching**

```
NSError *sessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&sessionError];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error: nil];

self.player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl.com:8040/;stream.mp3"]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAudioSessionEvent:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];




- (void) onAudioSessionEvent: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    //Check the type of notification, especially if you are sending multiple AVAudioSession events here
    NSLog(@"Interruption notification name %@", notification.name);

    if ([notification.name isEqualToString:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification]) {
        NSLog(@"Interruption notification received %@!", notification);

        //Check to see if it was a Begin interruption
        if ([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan]]) {
            NSLog(@"Interruption began!");

        } else if([[notification.userInfo valueForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded]]){
            NSLog(@"Interruption ended!");
            //Resume your audio
            NSLog(@"Player status %i", self.player.status);
            // Resume playing the audio.
            [self.player play];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Having the same issue still. PlayAndRecord and Ambient session categories receive no "end of interruption" notification. SoloAmbient receives no notification at all.

Comment: Did you do call -removeObserver: somewhere?  I had a similar problem and that was the cause.  If you're like me, you might want to do a grep/find on "removeObserver" just in case your eyes don't see it...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with interrupts. [iOS: Siri not available does not return AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404463/ios-siri-not-available-does-not-return-avaudiosessioninterruptionoptionshouldre/24424225#24424225)

Ended up using applicationWillResignActive and applicationDidBecomeActive instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is Property of your AVCaptureSession instance: 
@property(nonatomic) BOOL usesApplicationAudioSession

It is YES by default just set it to NO, and will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add object:session

> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
>   selector:@selector(onAudioSessionEvent:)
>   name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:[AVAudioSession
>   sharedInstance]];

Comment: If it doesn't fire for `object:nil` it won't fire for anything else dude...