# iOS background mode is stop by other activity

Tags: ios, swift, background, appdelegate

I am developing a project that play music in the background.  Basically, the app will continue play the audio file even the screen is locked.

I have setup the background mode by selecting audio option, as you can see in this photo:
[image]

It works fine as I expected that the app keep playing the audio when users lock the screen.
However, when a call is received, the app stop playing.  I thought it may start playing again after the phone call finished. However, it didn't.

I check a few webs, should I do some modification in the AppDelegate file, such as this method:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)
```

Basically, what I am trying to figure out is, how can I pause the audio when phone call or other notifications come and resume playing the audio when the phone call or other notifications finished.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, It does not un pauses it self. Try registering AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification and once the interruption is done try un pausing the audio.

Comment: Check this out  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476698/background-audio-doesnt-resume-after-a-call?rq=1